# Is the python XOR bitwise operator not just a regular operator?

Tags: python, operators, bitwise-xor

Other questions on this site suggest that python has no XOR operator, only a bitwise operator `^`. But when I try this operator on booleans the result is also a boolean (Python 3.9.12)

```
True ^ False
>> True
```

If it was a bitwise operator I would expect it to first cast the inputs to integers, resulting in an integer as output. Is bitwise XOR still an appropriate name for `^`? And why doesn't python implement an XOR keyword to make it more python-esque?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values - `In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively.`. Python does not use keywords for other mathematical operators, why would it be python-esque to have one for XOR?

Comment: `True` and `False` *are*, for most purposes, the integers `1` and `0`. `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: `and` and `or` exist primarily because you can't do short-circuiting with ordinary functions. Remember, `x & y` is an ordinary expression equivalent to `x.__and__(y)`, and like any other function call, `y` must be evaluated before the call is made. `x and y` is special in that `y` is only evaluated if `x` is true. A hypothetical ``x xor y``, on the other hand, would still have to evaluate both `x` and `y` to produce a result, so there's no reason to add another special form to the language to do the exact same thing that `x ^ y` would do.

Comment: `bool` does override `__and__`, `__or__`, and `__xor__` to produce `bool` results, rather than inheriting those methods from `int`. That way `True & False == False`, though with no short-circuiting. Curiously, `bool` does *not* override `__invert__`, so `(~True)` and `(not True)` are different.

Comment: @IainShelvington I mean that I see the xor operator here as a logical operator, similar to `and` and `or`. Python aims to read like English so for me it was weird that one of the logical operators did not have an 'English' counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

*Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True. They are used to represent truth values (although other values can also be considered false or true). In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively. The built-in function bool() can be used to convert any value to a Boolean, if the value can be interpreted as a truth value (see section Truth Value Testing above).*

it is as if you are writing:

```
1^0
#output
1
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values

Comment: This is somewhat illuminating but it kind of sidesteps the question. Just because two object behave the same does not mean they are equal. For example `"1"`, `1` and `True` are different objects. Doesn't the fact that the output is a boolean mean it is *not* a numeric context but a logical one? (these two might be the same I do realize)